# Jersey: Default Cache Control to no-cache

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

While writing a RESTful web service, I am encountering issues if I enable any sort of caching on my client (currently a .NET thick client). By default Jersey is not sending any sort of cache control header, so the client is caching most pages automatically (which seems to be valid behaviour).

I would like to have Jersey by default send a cache control of "no-cache", and then in particular responses override the cache control.

Is there any way to do this with Jersey?

I've found that RESTeasy has the ability to use the @NoCache annotation to specify the setting for the whole class, but I've not found anything similar with Jersey.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is easy with Jersey by using a ResourceFilterFactory - you can create any custom annotation you attach to your methods to set cache control settings. ResourceFilterFactories get called for each discovered resource method when the application initializes - in your ResourceFilterFactory you can check if the method has your @CacheControlHeader annotation (or whatever you want to call it) - if not, simply return response filter that adds "no-cache" directive to the response, otherwise it should use the settings from the annotation. Here is an example of how to do that:

```
public class CacheFilterFactory implements ResourceFilterFactory {
    private static final List<ResourceFilter> NO_CACHE_FILTER = Collections.<ResourceFilter>singletonList(new CacheResponseFilter("no-cache"));

    @Override
    public List<ResourceFilter> create(AbstractMethod am) {
        CacheControlHeader cch = am.getAnnotation(CacheControlHeader.class);
        if (cch == null) {
            return NO_CACHE_FILTER;
        } else {
            return Collections.<ResourceFilter>singletonList(new CacheResponseFilter(cch.value()));
        }
    }

    private static class CacheResponseFilter implements ResourceFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {
        private final String headerValue;

        CacheResponseFilter(String headerValue) {
            this.headerValue = headerValue;
        }

        @Override
        public ContainerRequestFilter getRequestFilter() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public ContainerResponseFilter getResponseFilter() {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {
            // attache Cache Control header to each response based on the annotation value
            response.getHttpHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, headerValue);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

The annotation can look like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface CacheControlHeader {
    String value();
}
```

The ResourceFilterFactory can be registered in your application by adding the following init param to the definition of Jersey servlet in web.xml:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>package.name.CacheFilterFactory</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Thanks for summing this up so nicely. I had fumbled through this on my own, but this right up perfectly summarizes the "Right Way" to do this.

Comment: Is there a way to set cache control to no-cache for all methods without having to add the annotation for each one?

Comment: [Cache-Control Using Annotations With Jersey](http://alex.nederlof.com/blog/2013/07/28/caching-using-annotations-with-jersey/) is much cleaner and complete

Comment: Note that this solution only applies to Jersey version 1.x. Jersey 2.x does not have a ResourceFilters class, the package is org.glassfish.jersey vs com.sun.jersey, etc. The Jersey 2.x way to do this uses javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter.

Answer (score 14):

Based on the solution by @martin-matula I created two Cache annotations. One `@NoCache` for no caching at all and one `@CacheMaxAge` for specific caching. The `CacheMaxAge` takes two arguments so you don't have to calculate the seconds yourself:

```
@GET
@CacheMaxAge(time = 10, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
@Path("/awesome")
public String returnSomethingAwesome() {
    ...
}
```

The ResourceFilter now has this create method that by default doesn't interfere (so other caching mechanisms keep working):

```
@Override
public List<ResourceFilter> create(AbstractMethod am) {
    if (am.isAnnotationPresent(CacheMaxAge.class)) {
        CacheMaxAge maxAge = am.getAnnotation(CacheMaxAge.class);
        return newCacheFilter("max-age: " + maxAge.unit().toSeconds(maxAge.time()));
    } else if (am.isAnnotationPresent(NoCache.class)) {
        return newCacheFilter("no-cache");
    } else {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}

private List<ResourceFilter> newCacheFilter(String content) {
    return Collections
            .<ResourceFilter> singletonList(new CacheResponseFilter(content));
}
```

You can see the full solution [in my blogpost](http://alex.nederlof.com/blog/2013/07/28/caching-using-annotations-with-jersey/).

Thanks for the solution Martin!

Answer (score 8):

@martin-matula's solution does not work with JAX-RS 2.0 / Jersey 2.x as ResourceFilterFactory and ResourceFilter have been removed. The solution can be adapted to JAX-RS 2.0 as follows.

Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface CacheControlHeader {
  String value();
}
```

DynamicFeature:

```
@Provider
public class CacheFilterFactory implements DynamicFeature {

  private static final CacheResponseFilter NO_CACHE_FILTER = 
          new CacheResponseFilter("no-cache");

  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, 
                        FeatureContext featureContext) {

    CacheControlHeader cch = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod()
            .getAnnotation(CacheControlHeader.class);
    if (cch == null) {
      featureContext.register(NO_CACHE_FILTER);
    } else {
      featureContext.register(new CacheResponseFilter(cch.value()));
    }
  }

  private static class CacheResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    private final String headerValue;

    CacheResponseFilter(String headerValue) {
      this.headerValue = headerValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext,
                       ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) {
      // attache Cache Control header to each response
      // based on the annotation value                     
      containerResponseContext
              .getHeaders()
              .putSingle(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, headerValue);
    }

  }
}
```

CacheFilterFactory needs to be registered with Jersey. I'm doing it via Dropwizard - using environment.jersey().register() - but on standalone systems I understand this can be done for example by letting Jersey scan your classes for @Provider annotations by defining the following in your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my.package.MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <!-- Register resources and providers under my.package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

See [this post](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/) for more information about registering components.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the

```
isNoCache(true)
```

which will stop caching in the browser.

See:

http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.12/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/CacheControl.html#isNoCache%28%29

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that on a given single Response, I was hoping to have something at a higher/more generic level.

Answer (score -2):

I found one annotation which can disable caching. You can use following annotation for your API:

```
@CacheControl(noCache = true)
```

Ref: [Jersey Annotation for cache control](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/CacheControl.html)

Comment: You are linking to a class org.springframework.http.CacheControl from Spring which is not an annotation either.You probably meant javax.ws.rs.core.CacheControl which is also not an annotation.