# How to set Pragma: no-cache HTTP header in Jersey?

Tags: java, jersey, cache-control

I need to force browser loading web resource from URL, not from browser cache. How can I set up `Pragma: no-cache` HTTP header in **[Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html)** responce?

Code:

```
@GET @Path("/cache/{id}")
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public static String getCachachedJSON(@PathParam("id") int id) {  
        return  getJSONRecord(id);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Solved by implementing `ContainerResponseFilter` and overriding `filter` method.

Comment: Check this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934316/jersey-default-cache-control-to-no-cache

Answer (score 0):

Add the response as a `@Context` resource, it can be a parameter or a field, too:

```
getCachachedJSON(@PathParam("id") int id, @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse)
```

Then use the `addHeader` function:

```
servletResponse.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

Comment: Jersey web serwer fails to start when `@Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse` added. How to set up Jersey servlet support without maven and preserve current URL structure?